# Metal objects through X Ray (cabinet scanners) daily

Tags: radiation

I work in a secure facility where all my belongings have to be x rayed daily. Is there any possibility that metal objects such as watches, keys, coins etc. can absorb any harmful radiation?   Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics Stack Exchange](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1505)! According to the [help/on-topic], Skeptics is for researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read. This question doesn't appear to address any claim and has been put on hold as off-topic as it is our policy.